# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having trouble with this problem. I've tried many things but I couldn't find any solution for this :(

> Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_stmt_get_result() in /home/storage/d/24/41/suprcarrinhos1/public_html/carrinhos-de-cliente.php:40

My PHP Version: 7.1.13

The code:

```
<?php
    $sqlprodutos = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE categoria = 'Carrinhos de Cliente' ORDER BY ordem ASC";
    $stmtprodutos = mysqli_stmt_init($con);
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sqlprodutos);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmtprodutos, $sqlprodutos)) {
        echo "Erro. Por favor, tente novamente mais tarde.";
    } else {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($res) == 0){
?>
        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                      <h3 class="text-center">Ops! Nenhum produto foi encontrado.</h3>
                      <br>
                    </div>
                  </div>
<?php
        } else{
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmtprodutos);
            $resultprojetos = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmtprodutos); <---- This is the Line 40

            while($scprodutos = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    
                $id_produto        = $scprodutos['id'];
                $nome_produto      = utf8_encode($scprodutos['nome']);
                $tipo_produto      = utf8_encode($scprodutos['tipo']);
                $imagem_produto    = $scprodutos['imagem'];

                $link_produto = preg_replace('/[ -]+/' , '-' , $nome_produto);
?>
        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 mb-3">
        <a href="produto.php?p=<?php echo $link_produto; ?>&id=<?php echo $id_produto; ?>" class="text-decoration-none">
            <div class="card mb-5 h-100 shadow-sc">
              <img src="assets/img/produtos/<?php echo $imagem_produto; ?>" class="card-img-top my-3" alt="<?php echo $nome_produto; ?> - <?php echo $tipo_produto; ?>">
              <div class="card-body product">
                <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase text-center"><?php echo $nome_produto; ?></h5>
                <div class="bottom">
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-uppercase text-center"><?php echo $tipo_produto; ?></h6>
                    <div class="d-grid gap-2 mb-4">
                        <a href="produto.php?p=<?php echo $link_produto; ?>&id=<?php echo $id_produto; ?>" class="btn btn-dark">Ver detalhes</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
<?php
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: if, else, and another else?

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel That are different if and else statements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli\_stmt\_get\_result()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001819/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-mysqli-stmt-get-result)

Comment: The PHP version you are using hasn't been supported in a long time. Consider upgrading soon

Comment: @AaronJunker this server is located in shared hosting. I can't install this driver I guess :( The same website works perfectly on a different shared hosting I've tested.